# Ratchet wsserver's enableKeepAlive isn't closing connections?

Tags: php, ratchet

## Info

The enableKeepAlive configuration doesn't seem to work and the documentation doesn't even explain how to properly set it. http://socketo.me/docs/websocket

I tested it by using a phone to open a connection then turning off both wifi and data. The client was never disconnected.

## my code : chat-server.php

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\OriginCheck;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$loop->run();
$checkedApp = new WsServer( new Chat() );
$checkedApp->enableKeepAlive($loop, 5);
//$checkedApp = new OriginCheck(new WsServer( new Chat() ), array('localhost'));
$checkedApp = new OriginCheck($checkedApp);
$checkedApp->allowedOrigins[] = 'mywebsite.com';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        $checkedApp
    ),
    8082
);

//works, so loop works
/*
$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(5, function () use ($server) {        
    foreach ($server->app->clients as $client) {                  
            $client->send("hello client");          
    }
});
*/

$server->run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Awesome, so it was covered in on this page:
http://socketo.me/docs/migration-3

After creating the server, you then enableKeepAlive:

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\OriginCheck;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
//$loop->run();
$checkedApp = new WsServer( new Chat() );
//$checkedApp->enableKeepAlive($loop, 5);
//$checkedApp = new OriginCheck(new WsServer( new Chat() ), array('localhost'));
$checkedAppToPass = new OriginCheck($checkedApp);
$checkedAppToPass->allowedOrigins[] = 'mywebsite.com';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        $checkedAppToPass
    ),
    8082
);

$checkedApp->enableKeepAlive($server->loop, 10);

//works, so loop works
/*
$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(5, function () use ($server) {        
    foreach ($server->app->clients as $client) {                  
            $client->send("hello client");          
    }
});
*/

$server->run();
```

Comment: Doing it exactly this way but it doesn't work.